# Can i post my edited information in CKEditor?

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor

CKEditor is a word like html editor.
[image]

There is a option like saving file
however, this is a `javascript:void('save')` function, can i modify this save button so that it can post the data into another php page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this one http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/4507.